# First scroll down display popup second time scroll down should not display popup using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I am trying to display popup when scroll down. Certain point popup will display that is working fine the code is below.

```
<div id="spopup" style="display: none;" class="news_sletter">
                            <a style="position: absolute; top: 7px; right: 10px; color: #555; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return closeSPopup();">
                                <img src="images/ico-x.png" width="18" height="18" style="background: #fff;" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="side_bar_sub_heading">
                                <h6>Newsletter </h6>
                            </div>

                            <p>Subscribe to our email newsletter for useful tips and resources.</p>

                            <form>
                                <div class="form-group blog_form">
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email Address">
                                </div>

                                <div class="search_btn-3">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Subscribe </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
```

**Jquery code is below**

```
<script>
 var isAlreadyPopUp = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if(!isAlreadyPopUp){
            if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() / 25)
        $("#spopup").show("slow"); else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
     }
});
function closeSPopup() {
    $('#spopup').hide('slow');
}
</script>
```

**and CSS is**

```
<style type="text/css">
    /* popup css*/
    #spopup {
        background: hsl(0, 0%, 0%) none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border-radius: 9px;
        -moz-border-radius: 9px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px #333;
        box-shadow: inner 0 0 3px #333;
        padding: 27px;
        width: 300px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 40%;
        display: none;
        z-index: 10;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
```

My requirement is once user do not want subscribe he will click on close button popup will close successfully, later after five or ten mins again we want to display popup automatically.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a global variable.

```
var isAlreadyPopUp;
```

And you can set the value to 'true' or 'false' according to your need. In this case, while closing, or already scrolled etc.. like below.

```
isAlreadyPopUp=true;
```

And once after it, you can always check the *isAlreadyPopUp* value, if it is true, you don't need to execute your pop up show code.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
        if(!isAlreadyPopUp){
                if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() / 25)
            $("#spopup").show("slow"); else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
         }
    });
    function closeSPopup() {
        $('#spopup').hide('slow');
 }
```

**Edit:-**

You can use a setTimeout function for opening the popup in a time interval.

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
```

Comment: I need to display popup automatically after five or ten mins if user not subscribe and user if close the popup with help of close button

Comment: You can use a setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000); for that. And please accept as answer it it helps, that's how we say thanks in StackOverflow. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure I will accept. I tried with set time out but it is not working

Comment: In the setTimeout function you need to make the variable value as false too. Please check whether you have done that too.